# Chartjs Real Time chart like Windows performance chart

Tags: charts, real-time, analytics, chart.js, react-chartjs

I want to make a real-time chart and want my window to be always of fixed size. i.e. I always want to show the data of 5 minutes in my chart. When I have 5 minutes of data shown on the chart, it should start removing the older data and only show the latest data also the labels should not increase on my chart x-axis. On the fiddle, you can see that as soon as the new data comes, the number of labels are increasing on the x-axis.

How can I make sure that chart always only shows data for last 5 minutes?

```
        var ctx = document.getElementById("chartData").getContext("2d");
    var LiveChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: data_live,
      options: live_options
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uLUAT/597/